# Xcode find in document stuck in case-sensitive

Tags: xcode

When in Xcode editing code for my objective C files, I often press Command-F to bring up the little Find-In-Document banner across the top. Sometimes this gets stuck in case-sensitive search, and when it does that it also won't loop through the entire document and sometimes won't even display the selected found string.

I can't find any options to turn off the case sensitivity, and I never intentionally turned it on. I've restarted xcode several times hoping that would be it but it's changed nothing.

Slightly off-topic, but this was the best place I could think of to ask this question. Thanks for any response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer elsewhere: Clicking the little magnifying glass on the left of the text field brings up a menu that lets you disable case sensitive and re-enable wrap around. Not sure how it got like that in the first place, but now I know it's blatantly easy to fix!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's safer to keep the case sensitivity always on and just turn it off on very specific cases, specially if you use the replace tool. Just my 2¢.